# Google Task Manager with Goole Consent with custom Consent Popup

Tags: google-tag-manager, gdprconsentform

I am following tutorial on [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/consent?consentmode=advanced) which gives me implementation example of setting default consent and updating it and is as following:

```
<script>
  // Define dataLayer and the gtag function.
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

  // Set default consent to 'denied' as a placeholder
  // Determine actual values based on your own requirements
  gtag('consent', 'default', {
    'ad_storage': 'denied',
    'ad_user_data': 'denied',
    'ad_personalization': 'denied',
    'analytics_storage': 'denied'
  });
</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!-- Create one update function for each consent parameter -->
<script>
  function consentGrantedAdStorage() {
    gtag('consent', 'update', {
      'ad_storage': 'granted'
    });
  }
</script>
<!-- Invoke your consent functions when a user interacts with your banner -->
<body>
  ...
  <button onclick="consentGrantedAdStorage()">Yes</button>
  ...
</body>
```

Yet, my consent is not reaching Google Tag Manager and not showing up in Google Tag Assistant.

My question is, do I need to make additional configuration somewhere so that after pushing new consent into dataLayer it will be sent to Google? Do I need to configure something in the Google Tag Manager environment to listen to the changes in the dataLayer and then act on them?